# Bug when trying to open a question reporting a bug

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug-reporting-process

<strike>Few minutes ago</strike>, there was a total mess in the meta main panel. Many users *were able* to post questions, but those questions *couldn't be opened* because of the... bug they were reporting (note the "1 view" count):

[image: bugs]

Many users couldn't reach posts that were reported the *same* issue, so they posted a new post - resulting many duplicates in less than 1 minute.

Is it possible to prevent posting new posts when there's a problem viewing posts? Or any other way to prevent such things in the future?

<sup>Side note: Your [hard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyrdu.png) [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRCQ2.png) is much appreciated!</sup>

Comment: This is not always easily to implement but it could be a service that checks if all is well allow for posting else don't.  Some sort of web service call...

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: People cannot view questions and your reaction is to block them from asking them also? I don't think SO hates users that much.

Comment: @nwp So you prefer to be able to ask, but then fail immediately when try to open *your* own question that you've just posted?

Comment: I prefer being able to open the question. Failing to open a question is a critical bug that must be fixed immediately. Trying to make that critical bug slightly more bearable, if even, by blocking the other critical function of this site seems silly. May as well pull the plug of the server and concentrate on fixing the first problem.

Comment: Now *that's* what I call a meta question!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be that one :

If too many questions are tagged with bug, display a message that there seems to be something wrong. And as soon as the bug has been fixed do the following:
Take all questions that are tagged with "bug" and issue a notification to all the people who opened them that they should review them and in case they are still valid push a certain button. Otherwise the question will be closed after a certain time (e.g. 1 day).

Or close all questions with the exceptional possibility to re-open them within, say, a week.

This would not kill everything but facilitate the clean up later

Answer (score -1):

Such a feature may be difficult to implement.

Might I suggest that the number of questions tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is monitored by the system? As in if a certain amount of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions are posted within a short space of time, then disable posting of questions with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag & display a message informing the user that the Stack Exchange network may be experiencing issues.

There'd still be *some* duplicate questions related to the same issue, but however it'll tone down the amount. It's perfectly possible for users to bypass the 'lockdown' by posting without [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), however.

---

With the recent issue (which [turned out to be an error in the underlying software](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/714446403548872704)), many of the duplicate questions relating to the issue were posted *after* the [Stack Overflow team became aware of the issue](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/714492070803542017).

Perhaps the proper response when the team discovered the issue was to put the Network in read-only mode (or perhaps like my suggestion with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) earlier, automatically put the Network/affected site(s) into read-only mode when a certain volume of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions come flooding in, would have to be a high volume though)?

I realise that automation isn't always a good thing, but if applied carefully I think it might be useful in this situation.

Comment: @rene True, but then if a similar issue occurs again (aka, when users can post questions but there's some other error) it'll happen again. It doesn't even have to be the issue that happened today; refer to the mass postings of the same question in [tag:facebook] that happened last week when Facebook was experiencing a fault (*and that wasn't even a Stack Exchange issue*). I guess what I'm saying is this: true, you can't automate against something you don't know whether it'll happen or not, but you *can* automate against something that you *know* will happen.

Comment: The major issue here is that users will always find ways to bypass anything you throw at them, in this case it is avoiding using the [meta-tag:bug] tag at all. As I said, any automation applied would need to be tightly controlled, the ideal certainly wouldn't be read-only mode in just five questions in one minute tagged [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: _Bug: can't post questions tagged [meta-tag:bug]_

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom ..which is why I suggested an error message is shown informing the user that there are currently issues: `display a message informing the user that the Stack Exchange network may be experiencing issues.`.